# How to get input into a messageBox

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm fairly new to C++. I tried practicing my code but I hit an error I'm not sure how to fix:

> Error: expression cannot be used as a function

```cpp
switch (message)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
        TextBox = CreateWindow("EDIT",
            "",
            WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER,
            10,10,80,20,
            hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);

        BUTTON = CreateWindow("BUTTON",
            "GO",  
            WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER,
            100,10,70,20,
            hwnd,(HMENU)1,NULL,NULL);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:

    case 1:
        int gwtstat=0;
        //char *t=&textSaved[0];
        gwtstat=GetWindowText(TextBox,&textSaved[0], 50);
    
        ::MessageBox(
                hwnd,
                "I am" ()textSaved "and i am Beautiful!",
                "smile",
                MB_YESNO);
```

Comment: `"I am" ()textSaved "and i am Beautiful!"` is not valid syntax. It looks like you're treating the string literal `"I am"` as a callable object by following it with `()`. You need to join your strings a different way.

Comment: Try `"I am " + textSaved[0] + "and i am Beautiful!"` as second parameter to `::MessageBox`

Comment: @Aamir `textSaved` looks to be a text buffer not a `std::string` object so that expression won't work. And `textSaved[0]` would result in getting only the first character, not the saved string. I would try something like `"I am "s + textSaved + " and I am Beautiful!"s`. Note the `s` suffixes on the string literals.

Comment: hmm.. i thought it was string, I infer it from the above statement `gwtstat=GetWindowText(TextBox,&textSaved[0], 50);`. We need more information.

Comment: You could be right. I inferred character array from the same code :-). More info is definitely required.

Comment: @Aamir [`GetWindowText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) takes a pointer to a char array, not a `std::string`.

Comment: If you need string interpolation, use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) (requires C++20, which Visual Studio fully supports). Something like this: `std::format(L"I am {} and i am Beautiful!", textSaved).c_str()`. Also get into the habit of using the Unicode versions of the API, e.g. `MessageBoxW` instead of `MessageBox` (scroll to the bottom of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw) to learn more).

Comment: If you don't have C++20, just use `std::string` concatenation instead, eg: `::MessageBox(..., (std::string("I am ") + textSaved + std::string(" and i am Beautiful!").c_str(), ...);` Or, if you have C++14 at least: `using std::literals::string_literals; ::MessageBox(..., ("I am "s + textSaved + " and i am Beautiful!"s).c_str(), ...);` Otherwise, use a `std::ostringstream` instead: `ostringstream oss; oss << "I am " << textSaved << " and i am Beautiful!"; ::MessageBox(..., oss.str().c_str(), ...);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```cpp
"I am" ()
```

The expression `"I am"` is of type `char const[5]` which doesn't support function call syntax. What you intended to do is probably string interpolation. For that you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) starting with C++20.

The following solves the immediate issue:

```cpp
::MessageBox(
        hwnd,
        std::format("I am {} and i am Beautiful!", textSaved).c_str(),
        "smile",
        MB_YESNO);
```

There are lots of other issues with the code, some less fatal than others:

- Use of the ANSI API as opposed to the Unicode API. The latter is *strongly* recommended, as it allows use of the entire set of Unicode code points (and has less overhead)
- Assigning terribly low IDs to controls (0 and 1, respectively) (see [Why do dialog editors start assigning control IDs with 100?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041214-00/?p=37013) for details)
- Defining a variable in a `case` label; your compiler warned you about this
- Failure to extract the control ID from the [`WM_COMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command) message handler

A more appropriate implementation could look like this:

```cpp
// Declare symbolic constants for control IDs
constexpr int TextBoxId = 100;
constexpr int GoButtonId = 101;

// ...

switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
    TextBox = ::CreateWindowW(L"EDIT",
        L"",
        WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER,
        10,10,80,20,
        hwnd,(HMENU)TextBoxId,NULL,NULL);

    BUTTON = ::CreateWindowW(L"BUTTON",
        L"GO",  
        WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER,
        100,10,70,20,
        hwnd,(HMENU)GoButtonId,NULL,NULL);
        break;

case WM_COMMAND:
    // Evaluate control ID of the sender
    switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {

    case GoButtonId: {
                  // ^ Introduce new scope for automatic
                  //   lifetime management of local variables
        // Retrieve text from text box
        size_t const length = ::GetWindowTextLengthW(TextBox);
        std::wstring text(length, L'\0');
        ::GetWindowTextW(TextBox, text.data(), text.length() + 1);
    
        ::MessageBoxW(
                hwnd,
                std::format(L"I am {} and i am Beautiful!", text).c_str(),
                L"smile",
                MB_YESNO);
        // ...
        }
        break;
```

While this implementation reads the edit control's contents into a `std::wstring` variable the following will work as well, and doesn't require C++20 (compiles with C++98):

```cpp
::MessageBoxW(
        hwnd,
        (L"I am " + text + L" and i am Beautiful!").c_str(),
        L"smile",
        MB_YESNO);
```

Comment: Another issue is that the `case GoButtonId:` (or `case 1:` in the original code) statement immediately following the `case WM_COMMAND:` is a fall-through case, regardless of how it is indented. There needs to be another `switch` on the value of wParam.

Comment: That's fixed now, thanks @jkb.